# Problem using TVN_SELCHANGED seems to go in a continuous cycle

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have this event handler in a modelless popup dialog tree control:

```
void CAssignHistoryDlg::OnTvnSelchangedTreeHistory(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTREEVIEW    pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    if (!m_bBuildTreeMode)
    {
        if ((pNMTreeView->itemOld.hItem == nullptr && !m_bFirstSelChangeEvent) ||
            pNMTreeView->itemOld.hItem != nullptr)
        {
            m_bFirstSelChangeEvent = true;
            if (m_treeHistory.GetParentItem(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem) == nullptr)
            {
                // We must update the correct combo
                // and associated string (in the SERVMEET_S structure)
                if (m_pCombo != nullptr && m_pStrText != nullptr)
                {
                    CString strExtractedName = ExtractName(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem);
                    m_pCombo->SetWindowText(strExtractedName);
                    *m_pStrText = strExtractedName;
                }

                GetParent()->PostMessage(UM_SM_EDITOR_SET_MODIFIED, (WPARAM)TRUE);
            }
        }
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why once this event is triggered is that it goes in a continuous cycle.

Does anything jump out at you as wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure that it's *wrong* but calling `PostMessage` from *inside a message handler* looks a bit suspicious at a quick glance.

Comment: @AdrianMole I just wanted the parent dialogue to update its window title (add asteroid). So my user message in the parent then calls SetModified(wparam). I assumed using post message was the right way.

Comment: Like I said - not sure. But does the `UM_SM_EDITOR_SET_MODIFIED` message do anything that may 'update' the tree view itself? Maybe, as a 'debug' step, add a 'global' variable that stops that `PostMessage` call from recursion?

Comment: If *all* you want to do is update the title, you can use `GetParent()->SetWindowText(...)` (so long as you know what the text is).

Comment: Hi @AdrianMole. I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the message seemed to be going in a continuous cycle. Maybe it was because I was inserting breakpoints or adding temporary popup message boxes to debug. Either way, I worked out the minor adjustment I needed:

```
void CAssignHistoryDlg::OnTvnSelchangedTreeHistory(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTREEVIEW    pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    if (!m_bBuildTreeMode)
    {
        if ((pNMTreeView->itemOld.hItem == nullptr && !m_bFirstSelChangeEvent) ||
            pNMTreeView->itemOld.hItem != nullptr)
        {
            m_bFirstSelChangeEvent = true;
            if (m_treeHistory.GetParentItem(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem) == nullptr)
            {
                // We must update the correct combo
                // and associated string (in the SERVMEET_S structure)
                if (m_pCombo != nullptr && m_pStrText != nullptr)
                {
                    CString strExtractedName = ExtractName(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem);
                    m_pCombo->SetWindowText(strExtractedName);

                    // Bug fix - Only set as modified if the name is different
                    if(*m_pStrText != strExtractedName)
                        GetParent()->PostMessage(UM_SM_EDITOR_SET_MODIFIED, (WPARAM)TRUE);

                    *m_pStrText = strExtractedName;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have changed how and where I post the `UM_SM_EDITOR_SET_MODIFIED` message. This causes my application to work correctly. Previously it was always setting it as modified (multiple times). So even if you had just saved the file, it then was marked as modified again. This problem no longer happens.

Comment: I am curious if the `itemOld.hItem` is the same as `itemNew.hItem` in such case...

Comment: @VladFeinstein, you mean when `*m_pStrText == strExtractedName`, that the handles you stated might be the same, right?

Comment: Yes; I am trying to see if the notification can be dropped sooner based on that condition. And may be speculate about the reason - why are you getting it? Also, is there a chance that there is NO new item (the selection is simply removed)?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I tested and no debug message displayed when I tested the scenario I was interested in. Don't worry, it seems to work ... :)